# SCNView is being nil for some reason

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

The sceneView is nil for some reason. I have debugged it. For some reason I am getting a fatal nil error at one of the lines below (shown). I have no idea as everything seems correct.

```
 import UIKit
    import QuartzCore
    import SceneKit

    class GameViewController: UIViewController {


        var sceneView: SCNView!

        var gameScene: BirdScene?

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            gameScene = BirdScene(create: true)
            // fatal error at the line bellow
            sceneView.scene = gameScene
            sceneView.delegate = gameScene
            // background color to blue
            sceneView.isPlaying = true
            sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.53, green: 0.99, blue: 1, alpha: 1)

            print("Fjkdfkj")
            view.addSubview(sceneView)


        }
    }
```

Comment: Was your problem resolved?

Answer (score 0):

`sceneView` is not yet initialized in your case. You are assigning `gameScene` to `sceneView.scene`, however `sceneView` is `nil`.

This is one of the reasons why should never force unwrap.